# Seeking SheetSet functionality in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, layouts, template

Does anybody know of a SheetSet-type functionality in QGIS (similar to Autocad), i.e. a function capable of exporting several different QGIS layouts and merging them to 1 file (pdf)?

There is of course the Atlas generation tool, but that runs on features of a specified layer, not on layouts. And the layout's 'Add item/page from Template' tool is also not an ideal solution, since working on complicated models with many (raster) layers means having 10+ huge (A1 or A0) pages in a single layout is hardly practical to scroll or work with.

Comment: Maybe you could tell a bit more about the size of your area and the desired scale, as well as the contents of the maps. Furthermore, it is unclear to me, whether you are interested in a PDF with several pages, or what exactly the SheetSet produces.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered the Maps Printer plugin, which is exactly what I was looking for, except it doesn't merge the pdfs into 1 file. But I'll work around it.